# Identify operating system

Tags: operating-system, fortran, fortran90, intel-fortran

My Fortran 90 code on Intel compiler depends on the operating system it is running on, e.g.

```
if (OS=="win7") then
   do X
else if (OS=="linux") then
   do y
end if
```

How do I do this programmatically?

Comment: If you need a runtime check you might use `get_environment_variable("PATH",pathstring)`, then check if `pathstring` starts with `/`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use pre-processor directives for this task, see [here](http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Predefined+preprocessor+macros) and [here](http://geco.mines.edu/guide/ifort.html) for details:

- `_WIN32` for Windows
- `__linux` for Linux
- `__APPLE__` for Mac OSX

Here is an example:

```
program test

#ifdef _WIN32
  print *,'Windows'
#endif
#ifdef __linux
  print *,'Linux'
#endif

end program
```

Make sure you enable the pre-processor by either specifying `-fpp`/`/fpp` or given the file a capital `F`/`F90` in the extension. 
You could do this in a central location, do define e.g. a constant describing the OS. This would avoid these Macros all over the place.

Please note that no macro for Linux is specified by `gfortran`. As it still defines `_WIN32`  on Windows, you can alternatively use `#else` if you just consider Linux and Windows:

```
program test

#ifdef _WIN32
  print *,'Windows'
#else
  print *,'Linux'
#endif

end program
```

Comment: Going this route http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2012/01/c_c_tip_how_use_compiler_predefined_macros_detect_operating_system might be useful. Also were it me I think rather than preprocessing the Fortran I'd write a little C function that determined the OS, use preprocessing on that to get the desired info as that's what these macros are designed for, and then call it from the Fortran.